# How to save nested mongoDB properties with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let say that i want to make a user schema with nested properties:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  /* ... some other properties ... */

  profile: {
    firstName: { type: String, default: '' },
    /* ... some other properties ... */
  },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Now if i want to save a user in a nodejs framework like ExpressJs, i will save it like so:

```
var user = new User({
  username: req.body.username,
  profile.firstName: req.body.firstName /* this is what i want to achive here */
});

user.save(function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('User created');
  }
});
```

And i want to know if my Schema is good, or it's best practice to make all the properties in the root, as this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  firstName: { type: String },
  /* ... some other properties ... */
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema is good, but you cant define nested properties on the root of a new object as you did in your second code sample without quoting them. It should look like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var User = mongoose.model('User', {
  username: String,
  profile: {
    firstName: String
  }
});

var user1 = new User(
{
  username: 'Zildjian',
  'profile.firstName':'test'
});

user1.save(function (err) {
    if (err) // ...
        console.log('meow');
    process.exit(0);
});
```

Although I would recommend nesting it properly like this

```
var user1 = new User(
{
  username: 'Zildjian',
  profile: {
    firstName:'test'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, i think the first example is good for me, just asking: why are you exiting the process after saving?!

Comment: and why recommending the 2nd example? is it best practice?!

Comment: I exit the process to avoid Ctrl+C by hand since its just a little test. I recommend the 2nd example because if you nest like this, some other properties might make it into 'profile', and nesting the notation allows you not to repeat yourself with the key names. Its not very important a matter, just a way to avoid typing too much when the code evolves.